# Terminal command to disable Mouse Keys accessibility feature

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon, accessibility

Running Ubuntu-server 17.04 x64 with Cinammon 3.2.7. It seems that the mousekeys function is enabled by default, which disables the numpad and turns it into a mouse emulator. Attempting to disable this from the Accessibility section of the system settings works only so long as the system remains on. Upon reboot, it reverts to being on.

One of two things happen in Accessibility after I boot with mousekeys enabled. Either the setting shows that the feature is on, and must be turned off, or the setting shows that it is off, and I need to enable it first, then disable it.

Since this is quite annoying to do each time I start the system, what would be the equivalent terminal commands? I already have a startup script to control fans and keyboard lighting, so I can just add the relevant lines to that file.